# Баннер с эффектом перелистывания мышкой

Tags: css, owl-carousel

Кто может помочь, хочу на сайт добавить баннер как на этом сайте - https://yavir2000.com/ Вижу что используется OWL-carusel но в стандартных решениях не вижу подобного эффекта. Кто сталкивался, есть ли готовые решения?

Comment: before/after называется , на github так и ищите

Comment: Спасибо за помошь!